# FFmpeg logging does not work from java command run

Tags: java, logging, command-line, ffmpeg

When I run the following code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("ffmpeg -I /path/to/video/kot.mp4 /path/to/picsdir/img%04d.jpeg 2> /path/to/log.log");
```

This command run as expected in the terminal, the problem is that it does not work from java code. Exactly logging!
Please help! Thanks!

Comment: All directories exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec is not shell interpreter.  If you what it to work like shell interpreter then you have to start the interpreter like so:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "ffmpeg -I /path/to/video/kot.mp4 /path/to/picsdir/img%04d.jpeg 2> /path/to/log.log"});
try (InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
        OuputStream out = p.getOutputStream()) {
    p.waitFor(); //wait for job to complete before destroying it.
} finally {
    p.destroy(); //cleanup resources and abort
}
```

This example is updated to keep up with [JDK-4801027: Clarify need to invoke Process.destroy](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6462165) and [JDK-6462165: Preach Process file handle hygiene](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6462165)

Otherwise, use the ProcessBuilder to start ffmpeg and in Java remap the output stream to the log file.